# Camera2 API video resolutions

Tags: android, video, resolution, android-camera2, samsung-galaxy

I'm using Camera2 to record videos. To get a list of available resolutions, we have 2 options:

```
List<android.util.Size> resolutions = Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
```

And:

```
// CAMCORDER_PROFILES is an int array listing all the profiles ids
for(int profileId : CAMCORDER_PROFILES) {

    if(CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(profileId)) {

        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(profileId);
        // Here we can get a resolution with profile.videoFrameWidth & profile.videoFrameHeight
    }
}
```

At first I was using option 2 only. It was working fine until I try on a Samsung Galaxy A3 2016. On this device, if I try to use the 1920*1080 resolution, it fails with this error:

> E/CameraDevice-0-LE: Surface with size (w=1920, h=1080) and format 0x1
>   is not valid, size not in valid set: [960x720, 880x720, 720x720,
>   720x480, 640x480, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]

To workaround it, I now get a profile whose resolution is in the result of map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class). I works, but the best profile I can use is 640x480, which is not enough for my needs.

Is there a way to use the 1920*1080 resolution with Camera2 on the A3? Or is that resolution usable only with the Samsung SDK???

EDIT: Here's what I do when I start the video recording:

```
private void startRecordingVideo() {

    if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewResolution) {
        return;
    }

    try {

        closeCaptureSession();
        setUpMediaRecorder();

        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        texture.setDefaultBufferSize( (int) mPreviewResolution.getWidth(), (int) mPreviewResolution.getHeight());

        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();

        // Set up Surface for the camera preview
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
        surfaces.add(previewSurface);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        // Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
        Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

        // Start a capture session:
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();

                // Start recording
                mMediaRecorder.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Log.e(this, "Unable to start recording video");
            }

        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A3 has a Legacy camera. This means that the camera2 API is a wrapper around the old Camera API. Quite often, this wrapper introduces more hassle than whatever it resolves. I recommend to work with this and other legacy devices directly through the old Camera API.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know that it provides legacy mode only, but I need Camera2. What I want to know is if my code is fine, or if there is a way to use 1920*1080 on the A3?

Comment: I guess this device has a bug in their implementation of the legacy API wrapper. Your code accurately follows the official [video recording sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video), so I don't think it's your fault. If I were in your position, I would have tried to run this sample on your device.

Comment: Thanks. The sample code gets the sizes from map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class) smaller or equal to 1080p. Seems to work, but some devices like the Nexus 5X support higher sizes. Seems the safest way is to do what I do: get the camcorder profiles whose resolutions are in map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class). Some sizes will be dropped but at least it shouldn't crash... Google really did a bad job here, there's no proper way to retrieve the supported sizes / fps / bitrate ><

Comment: That's true; if the camera has supports *some* sizes only for *some* fps, the API has no way to report this.

Comment: Yep >< . I ended up doing what I explained in my original post, and add special case for the devices I can test. That completely sucks, but I see no other way. Having to do that for the second iteration of such an important API is really... meh!